# Parsing NSArray for CLLocation Information

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, cllocationmanager

My iOS app uses the information provided by Apple, [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html), to get various location information about my user. [cllocationmanager](/questions/tagged/cllocationmanager) provides a method for getting location information about the user every-time it changes based on certain parameters:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
```

This method is absolutely amazing, and returns all of the data I need, however it returns it as a single value in an NSArray:

> <+37.33069626,-122.02967106> +/- 10.00m (speed 3.62 mps / course 82.41) @ 2/3/13, 4:42:58 PM Eastern Standard Time

This has all the information I need (by the way, what does the *course* variable stand for), but I can't figure out how to get it into a more usable form. By usable form, I mean simply the coordinates, time, speed, etc. all in separate NSString / NSDictionary / NSArray values. **How can I split the single NSArray value (shown above) into different parts?**

I've tried splitting the single NSArray value here using [nspredicate](/questions/tagged/nspredicate), but I could only get the NSPredicate to return a boolean value.

I've tried splitting it with the `componentsJoinedByString` method, however that can only split the array value with one string and there's no single string that every value can be consistently split by.

Any suggestions on how I can split up the pieces of data given to my iOS app through CLLocationManager? Are there methods or functions which could retrieve / split the same data in a more usable form.

### Edit

It seems there was a misunderstanding both on my part and others. I had thought that the `CLLocation` object was an NSArray object with one value. However, as I learned in the comments (thank you @holex) it is not.

Comment: 1. Why do you want to avoid loops and `if` statements? 2. What's wrong with using the returned `CLLocation` objects?

Comment: @H2CO3 That's what I'm asking. CLLocation returns everything as ONE single array value. I need the values split apart and I can't figure out how to split them.

Comment: No, it doesn't. It has various properties like `coordinate`, `speed`, `timestamp`, etc...

Comment: @RazorSharp, what you are seeing when you log the `CLLocation` is just only the `description` value of the current class. for further information here is the **[CLLocation Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html)**.

Comment: @H2CO3 Yes I realize it has various properties, however as I stated in my question it all comes out in ONE single array value. Also, is there a specific reason you've downvoted?

Comment: @holex Thank you for the helpful information, I didn't realize that - must've missed it in the docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this part](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/CLLocationManagerDelegate/CLLocationManagerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/CLLocationManagerDelegate/locationManager%3adidUpdateLocations%3a) of the doc, the array contains CLLocations objects. So, just retrieve and process them.

```
for (CLLocation *location in locations) {
  NSLog(@"Latitude: %f, Longitude: %f", location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude);
}
```

Comment: The CLLocation object is an object and not an array. It has various properties which the other guys here showed you how to access them.